# Constructor error anytime I use private variables in VS Code

Tags: c++, class, visual-studio-code, constructor

We're learning about constructors in class and I was trying to experiment with an overloaded constructor. When I run my program I keep getting an error written in the color red that says...

```
        ~
```

The ampersand (&) character is not allowed. The & operator is reserved for future use; wrap an ampersand in double quotation marks ("&") to pass it as part of a string.

^This only happens when I try to use private variables, when everything is public nothing goes wrong.

///Here's my code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class JCole {
private:
    string song;
    string album;
    int albumNum;

    JCole::JCole(string _song, string _album, int _Num) {
        song = _song;
        album = _album;
        albumNum = _Num;
    }
};

int main() {
    JCole album1("Punchin the clock", "The Off-Season", 6);
    JCole album2("ATM","KOD",5);
    cout << album1.song << " " << album1.album << " " << album1.albumNum << endl;
    cout << album2.song << " " << album2.album << " " << album2.albumNum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The little '~' goes with the paragraph below it. It sits right on top of it.

Comment: Pass the `std::string` type by reference or if the constructor doesn't change the parameter, by constant reference.  I don't think you want the compiler wasting time and space creating copies to pass to your constructor.

Comment: Search for *initialization lists* in your favorite C++ reference.  Might as well starting coding more efficiently at the beginning of your learning.

Comment: Tip: Stop `using namespace std` and embrace the `std::` prefix.

Comment: BTW, **your constructor is private because you haven't changed the access rights from the members section**.  Add a `public:` before the constructor declaration.  Don't create private constructors unless you have damn good reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constructor is declared as private because you haven't changed the access setting.

Try this:

```
    class JCole {
    private:
        string song;
        string album;
        int albumNum;
 // Insert:  
  public:   
        JCole::JCole(string _song, string _album, int _Num) {
            song = _song;
            album = _album;
            albumNum = _Num;
        }
    };
```

A private constructor is a nasty thing; only members of the class can call it.  Thus wreaking havoc with external code that wants to instantiate this class.

Also, you can use many `public:, private:, protected:` within your class and in any order.